# how to load html content in txt file for email confimation, have any suggestion how to do it?

Tags: javascript, html

> how to load html content in txt file for email confimation

here is my verify.txt file

```
{% load i18n %}{% blocktrans %}Hello {{user}}!

Please click the link below to verify your email address.{% endblocktrans %}

{{ verification_url }}

if clicking the linkabove doesn't work, please copy and paste the URL in a new browser instead.

Regards,
The Deebaco Development Team
```

i want to modify this txt file to html file like below,

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Google Map</h1>

<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

<script>
function myMap() {
var mapProp= {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
  zoom:5,
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=myMap"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about HTML-Editor? What’s the concrete issue?

Answer (score 0):

i just implemented **{% block html_body %}** then it's work perfect.

> {% block html_body %}
>
> {% blocktrans %}You're receiving this email because you need to
>   finish activation process on {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktrans %}
>
> {% trans "Please go to the following page to activate account:"
>   %}
>
> {{
>   protocol }}://{{ domain }}/{{ url|safe }}
>
> {% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}
>
> {% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}
>
> {% endblock html_body %}